# Mirrored image when capturing from webcam

Tags: windows, video, webcam, directshow, image-capture

I'm capturing images from a webcam using code based on the example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407288(v=vs.85).aspx#example_code

It works fine except one strange thing: the image is mirrored along its x-axis, means it is top-down (but not rotated by 180 degrees).

So how can this happen? Is there a DirectShow option that could cause such a behaviour?

Comment: Mirroring is enabled on camera, or a bug in the driver. Or, your filter graph catches some weird third party buggy filters which alter image prior to its displaying.

Comment: Amazingly it happens with two very different cameras, so I'd guess it is not a driver problem...

Comment: May be it is a feature and not a bug: what is the image orientation of the data that are returned by SampleGrabber->GetCurrentBuffer()? May be there the last row comes first in memory? That would explain why it it bottom-top-oriented...

Comment: Oh, I thought it's mirrored around the other axis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RGB frames typically have reverse order of rows, bottom-to-top. The rule is:

- RGB Pixel Formats

  - `BITMAPINFOHEADER::biHeight` > 0 - bottom-to-top rows
  - `BITMAPINFOHEADER::biHeight` < 0 - top-to-bottom rows
- YUV Pixel Formats

  - regardless from `BITMAPINFOHEADER::biHeight` sign (both positive and negative are valid) - top-to-bottom rows

While both positive and negative `biHeight` values are valid, negative are less spread and supported. Many filters will just reject formats with negative values.